# Changing select's display box to a button (like jQueryMobile)

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I was wondering if there was a way, using vanilla css/jquery/html to turn a normal select box into the one like jQueryMobile, where the text and everything is just replaced by a button.

(Won't mind if it's something from bootstrap or some other independent addon).

[image: button]

[image: expanded]

Comment: try this plugin http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Comment: @SanjeevK Which part of it should I be using?

Comment: what do you mean by which part? this plugin will replace your existing select style, follow their guides

Comment: @SanjeevK I don't see any particular thing that does what I want. The only part that resembles replacing the text line with a button is the remove options part. But that just removes the options, making the select useless.